# making synchrnous http call in a for loop angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, get

I have an array of url and the requirement is that I have to make http.get requests in a synchronous manner. Only after the first url call is successful, the second one should be called

```
for(var i in urlArray)
{
    /*do some operations and get the next url*/
    $scope.alpha(newURL);
}

$scope.alpha = function (newURL) {
    $http.get(newURL) // these calls should be synchronous
    .success(function () {
    })
    .error(function () {
    });
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: did you try using $q ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want call them sequentially, in that case, you can use something like a recursion, call the function inside the .success callback

```
var currentURL; // calculate teh currentURL
$scope.alpha(currentURL);

$scope.alpha = function (newURL) {
    $http.get(newURL) // these calls should be synchronous
    .success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
        //get the response
        //generate the new currentURL as per your need

        //keep a break condition, to exit
        $scope.alpha(currentURL);

    })
    .error(function () {
    });
}
```

2) alternately you can you $q, deferred calls to achieve this

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

It seems what you really want to is make the calls **sequentially**, not necessarily synchronously.

In that case, don't use a loop (because it's synchronous). Simply make the next call in response to the previous call.

Simplified example:

```
var i = 0;
makeRequest(urlArray[i], function success() {
  var nextURL = urlArray[++i];
  if (nextURL) {
    makeRequest(nextURL, success);
  }
});
```

where `makeRequest` is the function that makes the Ajax request and calls the callback on success:

```
function makeRequest(url, callback) {
    $http.get(url).success(callback);
}
```

Comment: how do i define makeRequest? the syntax, I mean.... with the above code, I am getting "ReferenceError: makeRequest is not defined"

Comment: Just like you define any other function, e.g. `function makeRequest(url, callback)  { ... }`. You can name it whatever you want, this is just an example.

Comment: Well, you have to replace the `...` with the code of the function.

Comment: There, I updated my answer. I didn't expect defining the function to be such a big problem.